# How can I tell if bitcoind is done reindexing?

Tags: bitcoind, reindex

I started reindexing yesterday and I've read around online. Some people claim it only takes a few hours, others say it takes a few days. How can I verify when it is done?

Comment: It will show in the Debug logs. You'll see a percentage complete or block height that it has indexed up to. I forget if it gives an estimate time remaining.